# Issue on Azure DevOps Repo (All Branches) - "Files are not found or you do not have permission - No item exist at path '/" at version 'Branch master'"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, branch, repo

I am having an issue on repo.

It works fine after I used it the last time (four days ago) and when I open it since yesterday, I cannot access the repo. Also, I can’t see the other branches of this repo but the other repos are all accessible.

[image: Figure 1 - File not found on the repo]

I'm only currently working on other branch, not the default branch (master) and I don't have any issue on my permission level.

When I click “Go to repository root” on Figure 1, nothing happens. I think because the master branch is the default branch.

I tried to ask all users of this repo and they also can't see it.

I always open my Azure DevOps on InPrivate/Incognito window then I also tried opening it on a normal window and still not working.

This is the result when I try to view history of master branch (default branch) as well as the other branches.

[image: Figure 2 - No results on master branch history]

What are the possible issues here and what are the things to do for troubleshooting?